# Problems with cin::getline in CDT Builder

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I use CDT Internal Builder and MS Visual C++ Toolchain in my project in Eclipse. The problem is that the compiler swears:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> & getline(char *, ?)
std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> & getline(char *, ?, char)
'
```

when I'm tapping something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
fstream fin;
char buf[256];

fin.open("in.txt", fstream::in);
fin.getline(buf, 256); // !!!!!

return 0;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. If you find a solution, please tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about this problem here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/274600/776516/#msg_776516

Basically, it is a bug in with the eclipse code analysis plugin (CODAN).